# NodeJS : outputting a string using Express EJS Template

Tags: node.js, express

I have a code where on error I return a status with an error message:

```
if (err){
        res.render('page1', {status:2, msg:'Server Error : Probable unable to connect'});
        return;
}
```

In my page1.ejs, I have coded the following way:

```
    var status = <%= status %>;
    alert ( 'The status = ' + status);
    if( status == 2)
    {
            var msg = "'" + <%= msg %> + "'";
            alert(msg);
    }
```

OR

```
    if( status == 2)
    {
            alert('"' + <%= msg %> + "'");
    }
```

I am trying to get the value of status and msg - but since 'msg' exists as multiple words I am not able to find a way to capture complete strings as passed from NodeJS. Firebug shows error as:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
alert('"' + Server Error : Probable unable to connect+ "'");
-------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
alert('<%= msg %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert for EJS, but maybe this could work `var msg = <%= msg %>; alert(msg);`? Or simply `alert(<%= msg %>)`?

Comment: It comes to same error either way : alert( Server Error : Probable unable to connect );